# Why is 'false' used after this simple addEventListener function?

Tags: javascript

What is the false for at the end? Thanks.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  alert("All done");
}, false);
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807436/difference-between-true-and-false-in-javascript-eventlistener/14807507

Comment: The answers to both of these questions are too complex to me. I found a simple explanation at Chris Ferdinandi's blog: _"Yes, you should absolutely always use it. It’s optional in most modern browsers, but in some earlier implementations, the listener doesn’t run if it’s excluded. Err on the side of caution and always include it."_ (https://gomakethings.com/when-do-you-need-to-use-usecapture-with-addeventlistener/)

Answer (score 415, accepted):

I checked MDN too, but I still didn't understand what the `useCapture` was for, so this answer is for those who still don't get it after having checked the official documentation.

So first of all, the following happens in almost all browers:

> In all browsers, except IE<9, there are two stages of event processing.
>
> The event first goes down - that’s called ***capturing***, and then ***bubbles up*** . This behavior is standartized in W3C specification.

which means no matter what you set the `useCapture` to, these two event phases always exist.

This picture shows how it works.

[image]

> According to this model, the event:
>
> Captures down - through 1 -> 2 -> 3.
>
> Bubbles up - through 3 -> 2 -> 1.

Then comes your question. The 3rd param called `useCapture` indicates on which of the two phases you want your handler to handle the event.

> `useCapture = true`
>
> The handler is set on the capturing phase. Events will get to it before getting to its children.
>
> `useCapture = false`.
>
> The handler is set on the bubbling phase. Events will get to it after getting to its children.

which means that if you write code like this:

```
child.addEventListener("click", second);
parent.addEventListener("click", first, true);
```

when clicking child element, `first` method will be called before `second`.

By default, the `useCapture` flag is set to **false** which means you handler will only be called during event **bubbling** phase.

For detailed info, [click this reference link](http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: Very nice and comprehensive answer. I understand it a lot better than I did now.

Comment: Very good explanation. The human touch, that is what makes the difference.

Comment: I really appreciate this explanation.

Comment: Great answer. Can you also explain which approach should be used when?

Comment: @RahulArora see https://gomakethings.com/when-to-use-use-capture-in-your-event-listeners/

Comment: The https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing link was very useful

Comment: Note that `useCapture = false` is default

Comment: So in your figure, the 'topmost element' would be a grandparent, the middle element would be a parent and the "innermost element" is the child. So basically false will trigger events from the children first, and true will trigger events from the grandparent first.

Answer (score 8):

According to [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener), the third parameter is:

> **useCapture**
>   If `true`, `useCapture` indicates that the user wishes to
>   initiate capture. After initiating
>   capture, all events of the specified
>   type will be dispatched to the
>   registered `listener` before being
>   dispatched to any `EventTarget`s beneath
>   it in the DOM tree. Events which are
>   bubbling upward through the tree will
>   not trigger a listener designated to
>   use capture. See [DOM Level 3 Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow)
>   for a detailed explanation.

Comment: I dont know so much about javascript, so i am having trouble in getting this answer. I actually don't know what is useCapture? Will you please tell me something about it.

Comment: @BikashChandraMondal check out the answer below.

Comment: Please explain, don't just copy/paste.

Comment: What a useless copy-paste.

Comment: If you think that _"It initiates capture, and else it'd bulbble-upward"_ is a helpful answer to _"what's `useCapture`"_, then you seriously need to get your mental health checked. This is a beginner question, which doesn't beg for more confusing terms, but you didn't even explain any new terms here, just copy-pasted, and added more confusion to the OP. The next thing I imagine a newbie would do after stumbling upon your answer at the top is leave programming for good. What the ### is wrong with you?

Answer (score 7):

@Libra's answer is very good, there just happen to be some people like me who understand better the interaction of the code with the machine.
So the following script should be explaining the event propagation.
What I'm trying to do based this [description schema](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow) is :
Following event flow down and up the following hierarchy :

```
<window>
<document>
<body>
<section>
<div>
<paragraph>
<span>
```

For the sake of simplicity we'll start at the body down to the span element registering handlers for the capturing phase, and back up to the body element registering handlers for the bubbling phase.
So the result would be node by node the direction taken by the event from the start to the end.
Please click "Show console " on the right panel of the snippet to access the logs

```js
    function handler(e){
        /* logs messages of each phase of the event flow associated with 
        the actual node where the flow was passing by */

        if ( e.eventPhase == Event.CAPTURING_PHASE ){
            console.log ("capturing phase :\n actual node : "+this.nodeName);
        }
        if ( e.eventPhase == Event.AT_TARGET){
            console.log( "at target phase :\n actual node : "+this.nodeName);
        }
        if ( e.eventPhase == Event.BUBBLING_PHASE){
            console.log ("bubbling phase :\n actual node : "+this.nodeName );
        }
    }

    /* The following array contains the elements between the target (span and you can
    click also on the paragraph) and its ancestors up to the BODY element, it can still
    go up to the "document" then the "window" element, for the sake of simplicity it is 
    chosen to stop here at the body element
    */

    arr=[document.body,document.getElementById("sectionID"),
    document.getElementById("DivId"),document.getElementById("PId"),
        document.getElementById("spanId")];

    /* Then trying to register handelers for both capturing and bubbling phases
    */
        function listener(node){
            node.addEventListener( ev, handler, bool )    
            /* ev :event (click), handler : logging the event associated with 
            the target, bool: capturing/bubbling phase */
        }
        ev="click";
        bool=true; // Capturing phase
        arr.forEach(listener);
        bool=false; // Bubbling phase
        /* Notice that both capturing and bubbling 
        include the at_target phase, that's why you'll get two `at_target` phases in
        the log */
        arr.forEach(listener);
```

```css
        p {
            background: gray;
            color:white;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 5px;
            border: thin solid black
        }
        span {
            background: white;
            color: black;
            padding: 2px;
            cursor: default;
        }
```

```html
    <section ID="sectionID">
            <div  id="DivId">
                <p id="PId">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis <span id="spanId">CLICK ME </span> imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosq.
                </p>
            </div>
    </section>
```

Notice that events such as focus don't bubble, which makes sens still he majority of events do bubble.