# What is the purpose of the object.addEventListener's useCapture parameter?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, addeventlistener

I am trying to understand what `true` or `false` does when adding addEventListener in Internet Explorer. According to Microsoft it is `useCapture`. If I add an event such as:

```
element.addEventListener('click', function_name, true);
```

It does not appear to change anything, the listener still works. Can anyone explain the purpose of `useCapture` parameter please?

Answer (score 13):

It is the optional `useCapture` parameter that specifies the event phase to add the event handler for:

> Events are handled in two phases: capturing and bubbling. During the
>   capturing phase, events are dispatched to parent objects before they
>   are dispatched to event targets that are lower in the object
>   hierarchy. During the bubbling phase, events are dispatched to target
>   elements first and then to parent elements. You can register event
>   handlers for either event phase.

**true** 
Register the event handler for the capturing phase.

**false**
Register the event handler for the bubbling phase.

You can read the eventPhase documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/ff974944(v=vs.85).aspx

EDIT:

Please read the following that describes the event order defined by bubbling and capturing with clear examples. http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: Hi,Thanks for you reply, but that really does not help me at all. I have no idea what it means. guess I just not care and use true seems to work, thanks for your reply.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you set the `useCapture` to true then the event uses  the capturing phase, if false (default) it uses the bubbling phase. What this means is clearly defined in the link I provided...Anyhow, I have added another link that explains more clearly. Basically it is the execution order in which events are fired.

Comment: @Wayneuser1168636 see the example in this reply, it helped me understanding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398290/unable-to-understand-usecapture-attribute-in-addeventlistener#answer-7398447