# Scala.js: Using addEventListener to add events to objects

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, scala.js

In JavaScript, the addEventListener() method is used like this:

```
object.addEventListener("click", myScript);
```

In Scala.js: I have a canvas, and I want to listen to clicks only on the canvas, not the entire document. In the Scala.js.dom library, addEventListener is defined as:

```
 def addEventListener(`type`: String, listener: js.Function1[Event, _], useCapture: Boolean = ???): Unit = ???
```

I'm not sure what "useCapture" refers to. But I tried:

```
dom.document.getElementById("canvas").addEventListener("click", {
(e:dom.MouseEvent) => { /*do something*/ }
}, false)
```

And the error message I got:

```
found   : org.scalajs.dom.MouseEvent => Unit
required: scala.scalajs.js.Function1[org.scalajs.dom.Event, _]
```

Can someone explain what "useCapture" refers to, and how to correctly use addEventListener in Scala.js?

Comment: Regarding `useCapture`, the following snippet is from the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Parameters):
"indicates that events of this type will be dispatched to the registered listener, before being dispatched to any EventTarget beneath it in the DOM tree."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error message you get is a perfectly normal type error: `addEventListener` expects a `js.Function1[dom.Event, _]`, but you're giving it a `js.Function1[dom.MouseEvent, _]`. Since the first argument is in contravariant position, this does not typecheck.

There are two solutions: either you make your function take a `dom.Event`, that you then cast to `dom.MouseEvent`, like this:

```
canvas.addEventListener("click", { (e0: dom.Event) =>
  val e = e0.asInstanceOf[dom.MouseEvent]
  ...
}, false)
```

or you use `onclick` which is more precisely typed:

```
canvas.onclick = { (e: dom.MouseEvent) =>
  ...
}
```

Comment: is there a `+=` operator (or similar), such as `canvas.onclick += { (e: dom.MouseEvent) => ... }`

Comment: @David Portarella: No, at least not in the default scalajs-dom facade. Maybe there exists a library out there that provides something like that.

Answer (score 1):

> Event capture is the process by which an EventListener registered on
>   an ancestor of the event's target can intercept events of a given type
>   before they are received by the event's target. Capture operates from
>   the top of the tree, generally the Document, downward, making it the
>   symmetrical opposite of bubbling which is described below. The chain
>   of EventTargets from the top of the tree to the event's target is
>   determined before the initial dispatch of the event. If modifications
>   occur to the tree during event processing, event flow will proceed
>   based on the initial state of the tree..

http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-basic

```
window.addEventListener("click", function(){console.log('something1')}, false);
window.addEventListener("click", function(){console.log('something2')}, true);
```

The order will be

something 2 (defined first, using capture=true)

something 1 (defined second using capture=true)

[Ref 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398290/unable-to-understand-usecapture-attribute-in-addeventlistener)

Note on the second ref: The order is not guaranteed!

**capture phase**

The process by which an event can be handled by one of the target ancestors before being handled by the target node.

[REF 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-basic)