# JS Popup interrupts execution of javascript

Tags: javascript, popup, dom-events

Suppose I have http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_prompt page. Now I have event listener on click action, something like this:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    MyMagicHere();
});
```

Now in case of clicking on button "Try it" `MyMagicHere()` is interupted by JS popup. I want `MyMagicHere()` to be performed even in case of clicking on this button. Is there any way/workaround how to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `useCapture` parameter of `addEventListener` to `true`. Then your listener will be executed in capture phase before being executed any event target.

```
document.addEventListener('click',function(){
   MyMagicHere();
}, true);
```

This is the concept of capturing and bubbling events. You can see more in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398290/unable-to-understand-usecapture-attribute-in-addeventlistener)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the 'mouseup' event instead of the 'click' event to trigger your MyMagicHere call, as it will fire before the 'click' event does on the button.

Comment: if I try your suggestion in chrome console it does not seem that this is working.

`var test = "";
document.addEventListener("mouseup", function(){
    test = "worked";
});

var test2 = "";
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){
    test2 = "worked";
});`

after click if I simply do `test` or `test2` it showing in both cases that `test=""` @cameron morrow

Comment: Are you sure that when you check the value of test or test2 you are in the same scope that you declared it in?

Comment: Right on! I'd recommend using @Madox2's answer though, it's a cleaner solution.