# Calling a function before any click event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I want to call a function every time before any click event handler method.
I know, inside the click handler method I can call my function first, but this quite cumbersome as I have to do this at so many place as well as I have to keep in mind the same for any future click events.

Comment: [Could you show us the code?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 11):

You can set a capture event handler on the `document` object (or any common parent) and it will be called first before the event handler on the individual object.  `capture` is the third argument to `.addEventListener()` which is normally optional and defaults to `false`, but if you pass `true` on a parent, then the event handler will be called first.

Here's an example:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function() {
   log("document capture click");
}, true);

document.getElementById("target").addEventListener("click", function() {
   log("element click");
}, false);

function log(x) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = x;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<div id="target">Some text to click on</div>
```

Here's a related question that helps to understand the capture flag: [Unable to understand useCapture attribute in addEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398290/unable-to-understand-usecapture-attribute-in-addeventlistener)

Answer (score 5):

I see two solutions here.

First is to use onmousedown that is fired before click event

```
document.querySelector('.selector').addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
    console.log('mousedown');
}

document.querySelector('.selector').addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log('click');
}
```

Other way is to use compose that will create new reusable function for you (npm i lodash.compose).

```
var compose = require(lodash.compose);
var firstFunc = function(e){
    console.log('first');
    return e; //if you want to use it in second function
};
var secondFunc = function(e) {
    console.log('second');
};

document.querySelector('.selector').addEventListener('click', compose(secondFunc, firstFunc));
```

Or you could save new func in variable;

```
var logFirstThanSecondOnClick = compose(secondFunc, firstFunc);
document.querySelector('.selector').addEventListener('click', logFirstThanSecondOnClick);
```

Simply compose do next

```
function compose(f, g) {
    return function(x) {
        return f(g(x));
    }
}
```

But lodash one is more complex inside.

Here is some math theory about function composition, if you are interested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition