# Event bubbling, addEventListener not cancelled

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, dom-events, event-bubbling

Was reading the Docs in MDN about `addEventListener`. Then I experimented a bit, ended up with the following code:

```js
const inner = document.querySelector('#inner').addEventListener('click',
  () => {
    console.log('inner');
  }, true);


const outer = document.querySelector('#outer').addEventListener('click',
  () => {
    console.log('outer');
  }, true);
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">click me</div>
</div>
```

I thought that by setting the third element of `addEventListener` to `true` it would stop the event propagation and thus would stop the event bubbling of the inner `div`.

- How is this not stopping the bubbling?
- How do I manage to stop the bubbling?

Comment: To stop bubbling issue you can use event.preventDefault() or event.stopPropagation()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to understand useCapture parameter in addEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398290/unable-to-understand-usecapture-parameter-in-addeventlistener)

Answer (score 0):

You should use **stopPropagation** for stopping event bubbling.

As per defined standards, it should be prohibited as it can lead to loopholes.

```js
const inner = document.querySelector('#inner').addEventListener('click',
  (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('inner');
  });


const outer = document.querySelector('#outer').addEventListener('click',
  () => {
    console.log('outer');
  });
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">click me</div>
</div>
```