# reasoning for useCapture in addeventListener?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, event-bubbling

I have 4 buttons that each play their own music when pressed. I needed something that pauses one music when another button is clicked so that I dont have all 4 music playing on top of each other. I found this code to solve it:

```
document.addEventListener('play', function(event){
var allAudios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
debugger;
for(var i = 0; i<allAudios.length; i++){
    if(allAudios[i] != event.target){
        allAudios[i].pause();
    }
}
}, true);
```

However, I'm not  understanding the exact purpose of the `true` at the end. I understand its telling the event listener to use capture event but when I set up an alert on the event target's parents, the order of events gets triggered up from the event target to its parents (bubbling) and parents to event target (capturing). Does anyone have an explanation to this phenomena and why useCapture is needed in this case to begin with?

I got the code from this website if anyone needs a reference.

https://teamtreehouse.com/community/auto-stop-when-playing-other-files

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**: because the `play` event doesn't bubble up and you want to listen (capture) all the play events happening in the `document`.

`useCapture` allows you to capture events that normally don't bubble up. In the context of the script you are referencing, you are listening for the `play` event. The `play` event doesn't bubble up like other events and you want to capture (listen to) all the `play` events happening in the `document`, so you enable `useCapture` to capture all the `play` events so you can know when to pause all other music playing.

How to know when you'll need to set `useCapture` to `true`:

> 1. Visit the [Event Reference page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events).
> 2. Click on the event you want to use.
> 3. Under "General info" at the top, look for whether "bubbles" is set to "yes" or "no".
>
> If the event doesn’t bubble and you’ll be listening for events on an element other than the one that will trigger the event, set use capture to true.

Source: https://gomakethings.com/when-to-use-use-capture-in-your-event-listeners/

**Edit**
More details in how `useCapture` works: [Unable to understand useCapture parameter in addEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398290/unable-to-understand-usecapture-parameter-in-addeventlistener)