# What does the true and false mean at the end of the addEventListener method

Tags: cordova, addeventlistener

Here is an example of Phonegap addEventListener method

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

Can anyone explain me what does the false mean or sometimes there is true at the end.

And one more thing..

navigator.accelerometer.getCurrentAcceleration(onSuccess, onError);

this example above says that if he successfully gets the current acceleration, fire the onSuccess function and if it doesn't then fire the onError function...right?
Am I right about the acceleration example and please explain me the addEventListener false and true meaning thank you very much.

Comment: My answer doesn't describe what you are looking for ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [difference between true and false in javascript eventlistener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14807436/difference-between-true-and-false-in-javascript-eventlistener)

Answer (score 1):

You will be amazed what you can find when you google before asking a question ...

> useCapture Optional 
>       If true, useCapture indicates that the user wishes to initiate capture. After initiating capture, all events of the specified type will be dispatched to the registered listener before being dispatched to any EventTarget beneath it in the DOM tree. Events which are bubbling upward through the tree will not trigger a listener designated to use capture. See DOM Level 3 Events for a detailed explanation. If not specified, useCapture defaults to false.
>   Note: useCapture became optional only in more recent versions of the major browsers; for example, it was not optional prior to Firefox 6. You should provide this parameter for broadest compatibility.

[developer.mozilla.org documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener)

> Required. Boolean that specifies whether the event needs to be captured or not.

[Full documentation](http://help.dottoro.com/ljeuqqoq.php)