# Reactjs - value undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First of all, I suspect that const vector object is probably in a wrong place but I don't know where to put it.
I'm trying to control the position of the SVG object with arrow keys. It does not seem to be able to access x.

```
class Circle extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { h, w, x, y, r, stroke, fill } = this.props;
    return (
      <svg height={h} width={w}>
        <circle cx={x} cy={y} r={r}
          stroke={stroke} strokeWidth="3" fill={fill} 
        />
      </svg> 
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      h: 100,
      w: 500,
      x: 50,
      y: 50,
      r: 40,
      stroke: "black",
      fill: "red"
    }
  }
  _currentPosition() {
    // Display the current position
    console.log(this.state.x, this.state.y);
  }

  _handleKey(e){
    // Define key codes and movement vectors
    const vector = {
        37: [-10, 0],
        38: [0, -10],
        39: [10, 0],
        40: [0, 10]
    };
    // Display the current position
    this.currentPosition;

    // Detect key presses and change the position accordingly
      if (e.keyCode in vector) {
      this.setState({
        x: this.state.x + vector[e.keyCode][0],
        y: this.state.y + vector[e.keyCode][1]
      })
        } 
  }

   componentDidMount() {
     document.addEventListener("keydown", this._handleKey, false);
  }
   render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <Circle { ...this.state } onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

I have got the error:

```
VM211 pen.js:76Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
_handleKey @ VM211 pen.js:76
```

The code it is:
http://codepen.io/wasteland/pen/GZvWeo?editors=0110

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `this.state` is undefined inside `_handleKey`. The solution is to bind the function to `this` inside your constructor like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this._handleKey = this._handleKey.bind(this)
  ...
  ...
```

This is generally how you allow class methods to access the class instance' `this`.

React docs on "No Autobinding": https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#no-autobinding

Comment: Wait, why does `this.state` become undefined inside `_handleKey`? Isn't `this` bound to the `App` object?

Comment: @AkshatMahajan No, `this` inside the function is not automatically bound to App `this` when using ES2015 class syntax.

Comment: Could you point to the relevant documentation on this? I've scoured the MDN pages and can't really find something that says the same. I'd like to know more about this behaviour.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan From the React docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#no-autobinding

Comment: @dannyjolie Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: I have just got confused. Why does my code even work? in the <Circle ../> declaration I set: onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}. The function handleKeyPress does not even exist? Why did it work?

Comment: @Wasteland Well, you did add `document.addEventListener("keydown", this._handleKey, false);` in the App componentDidMount :)

Comment: Thank you. Would you be able to elaborate on it? I am reading about capture (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657292/why-is-false-used-after-this-simple-addeventlistener-function) but I must say I don't understand much of it. I can remove the onKeyPress= altogether without affecting the code, it still works.

Comment: @Wasteland Don't worry too much about capturing, setting `false` usually make things behave as expected. Basically it's a way of preventing the default browser behavior on events with regards to how events propagate through the DOM hierarchy. The illustration in one of the answers in the post you linked to pretty much shows what's going on.

Comment: Thanks. So my passing onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress} to <Circle /> had really no impact in the first place. Shouldn't it be throwing any error that it refers to a non-existent function?

Comment: @Wasteland It would have thrown an error if the event was triggered. But in order to capture a key event on an element, that element must have focus, e.g. like an input field with the cursor in it. And I don't think that is possible to do on an SVG element without a few hacks.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense.