# How can I avoid using inline JavaScript for clickable tabs?

Tags: javascript, html, events, tabs, onclick

I need to create tabs that reveal content when clicked. I have found some code that provides the functionality I need from this [W3Schools Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp), although I want to avoid using the inline JavaScript to call the openCity() function. In the original code, each tab button was defined like so:

```
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
```

This works fine, but I would much rather avoid using JavaScript like this in any code if I can. It looks like the **event.currentTarget** property is one of the most important parts here for adding the **.active** class to the tabs when clicked, although I was wondering if there was another way to carry out the same process.

I have tried several different solutions but still have not been able to find the best one. In previous attempts I had a few errors such as an Uncaught TypeError for not being able to access the property of an undefined value. Now, no errors arise, but the page is just stuck on the first tab and the others do not work.

In the latest attempt, I tried looping through each tab and added an event listener to call the function on them individually, but am still new to using JavaScript and am unsure on what else to do. Please excuse any silly mistakes!

Please find the code below (HTML, CSS, and JavaScript).

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial;
        }
        .tab {
            overflow: hidden;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
        }
        .tab button {
            background-color: inherit;
            float: left;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            transition: 0.3s;
            font-size: 17px;
        }
        .tab button:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
        }
        .tab button.active {
            background-color: #ccc;
        }
        .tabcontent {
            display: none;
            padding: 6px 12px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-top: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks">London</button>
    <button class="tablinks">Paris</button>
    <button class="tablinks">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>London</h3>
    <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Paris</h3>
    <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Tokyo</h3>
    <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<script>
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (var i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        var name = tablinks[i].innerHTML;
        console.log(name);
        tablinks[i].addEventListener('click', openCity(name));
    }
    function openCity(cityName) {
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
        this.className += ' active';
        // event.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }
</body>
```

Comment: https://cssreset.com/create-html-tabs-using-css-and-javascript/

Comment: This looks good, thanks, but I'm afraid I just need a vanilla JavaScript solution for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had other ideas without using data attributes, but i think it's a correct way.
Probably code can looks like that:

```js
let handleClick = e => {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".active"), e => e.classList.remove("active")); // remove `active` class from every elements which contains him.
  e.target.classList.add("active");
  document.querySelector(`div.tabcontent[data-id*="${e.target.dataset.id}"]`).classList.add("active");
};

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks"), btn => btn.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false));
```

```css
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" data-id="1">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" data-id="2">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" data-id="3">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div data-id="1" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div data-id="2" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div data-id="3" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, this looks like a great solution, thanks! Please could explain it to me in a little more detail though, if you don't mind? I'm not too sure on what's going on as I haven't come across code structured like this before.

Comment: Sure, i can. ;)
When you've clicked at the tab button, script will gets a `data-id` attribute from clicked button and then tried to find div with `tabcontent` class and similar `data-id` attribute.  Then script will be add `active` class to an element which was found. [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) using to convert HTMLCollection to an Array and call  the map function.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that. Would you mind just explaining the last line of JavaScript for me, please? I understand the others, but I'm still not too sure on this last one, especially when passing 'false' with the function.

Comment: @Ichi i can't correctly explain that. You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25591239/6362442) answer for better understanding that moment.